# count elements falling within certain thresholds in array in matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, count

I have a huge vector. I have to count values falling within certain ranges. 
the ranges are like 0-10, 10-20 etc. I have to count the number of values which fall in certain range.

I did something like this :

```
for i=1:numel(m1)
if (0<m1(i)<=10)==1
k=k+1;
end
end
```

Also:

```
if not(isnan(m1))==1
x=(0<m1<=10);
end
```

But both the times it gives array which contains all 1s. What wrong am I doing?

Comment: As non of the answers explain why `(0<m1(i)<=10)==1` gives all ones, I thought a comment in order... MATLAB will evaluate this as follows: firstly `0<m1(i)` (is m1(i) greater than zero?) is evaluated, the result is `0` or `1` (true or false) secondly, using this result, `result<=10` is evaluated (is 0 or 1 less than or equal to 10?) which will always be true giving `1`, then `1==1` is evaluated which will always be true giving the result of `1` you are consistently getting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this (also works for non integers)

```
k = sum(m1>0 & m1<=10)
```

Comment: That's better I was thinking too much! +1,

Answer (score 1):

You can use [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html). Observe:

```
>> x = randi(40, 1, 10) - 20
x =
  -2    17   -12    -9   -14   -14    15     4     2   -14
>> x2 = x(0 < x & x < 10)
x2 =
   4     2
>> length(x2)
ans =
    2
```

and the same done in one step:

```
>> length(x(0 < x & x < 10))
ans =
    2
```

Answer (score 0):

to count the values in a specific range you can use `ismember`,

if `m1` is vector use,

```
k = sum(ismember(m1,0:10));
```

If `m1` is matrix use `k = sum(sum(ismember(m1,0:10)));`

for example,

```
m1=randi(20,[5 5])

 9    10     6    10    16
 8     9    14    20     6
16    13    14     7    11
16    15     4    12    14
 4    16     3     5    18

sum(sum(ismember(m1,1:10)))

12
```

Comment: We can do like this also, but i think it needs some modification. Anyway, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply do something like this?

```
% Random data
m1 = 100*rand(1000,1);

%Count elements between 10 and 20
m2 = m1(m1>10 & m1<=20);
length(m2) %number of elements of m1 between 10 and 20
```

You can then put things in a loop

```
% Random data
m1 = 100*rand(1000,1);

nb_elements = zeros(10,1);

for k=1:length(nb_elements)
    temp = m1(m1>(10*k-10) & m1<=(10*k));
    nb_elements(k) = length(temp);
end
```

Then `nb_elements` contains your data with `nb_elements(1)` for the 0-10 range, `nb_elements(2)` for the 10-20 range, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Matlab does not know how to evaluate the combined logical expression

```
(0<m1(i)<=10)
```

Insted you should use:

```
for i=1:numel(m1)
    if (0<m1(i)) && (m1(i)<=10)
        k=k+1;
    end
end
```

And to fasten it up probably something like this:

```
sum((0<m1) .* (m1<=10))
```

Comment: Matlab _does_ know how to interpret that expression (try it). It's only that it's not what the OP wants

Comment: Yes, it ist able to interpret it, but not in the mathematical sense that was intended by the questioner. And the main question was "What wrong am I doing?", which I tried to give an answer to.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can create logical arrays and then use element-wise multiplication. Don't know how fast this is though and it might use a lot of memory for large arrays.

Something like this

```
A(find((A>0.2 .* (A<0.8)) ==1))
```

---

Generate values

A= rand(5)

A =

```
0.414906   0.350930   0.057642   0.650775   0.525488
0.573207   0.763477   0.120935   0.041357   0.900946
0.333857   0.241653   0.421551   0.737704   0.162307
0.517501   0.491623   0.016663   0.016396   0.254099
0.158867   0.098630   0.198298   0.223716   0.136054
```

Find the intersection where the values > 0.8 and < 0.2. This will give you two logical arrays and the values where `A>0.2` and `A<0.8` will be `=1` after element-wise multiplication.

```
find((A>0.2 .* (A<0.8)) ==1)
```

Then apply those indices to `A`

```
A(find((A>0.2 .* (A<0.8)) ==1))

ans =

   0.41491
   0.57321
   0.33386
   0.51750
   0.35093
   0.76348
   0.24165
   0.49162
   0.42155
   0.65077
   0.73770
   0.22372
   0.52549
   0.90095
   0.25410
```